# Java error - not a statement, what does this mean?

Tags: java

I am trying to get my code to create the new constructor objects which I require to create a mobile phone object. I have tried naming the constuctor fields to create the object.

when I compile my code on this line `this.Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3 "GPS");` I get this error: not a statement, what does this mean??

UPDATED CODE!

my code:

```
   /**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author (Lewis Burte-Clarke) 
 * @version (14/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private String phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int  memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private String serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private String GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    // The constructor method

    public Mobile(String mobilephonetype, int mobilescreensize,
            int mobilememorycardcapacity,int mobilecameraresolution,String mobileGPS, String newserviceprovider) {
        this.phonetype =  mobilephonetype;
        this.screensize = mobilescreensize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = mobilememorycardcapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = mobilecameraresolution;
        this.GPS = mobileGPS;
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;
        // you do not use this ones during instantiation,you can remove them if you do not need or assign them some  default values 


        Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");
        1024 = screen size;
        2 = memory card capacity;
        3=resolution;
        GPS = gps;
       "verizon"=service provider;
        typeofcontract = 12;
        checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }


    }

    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
    public void displayMobileDetails() {
        System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
        System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
        System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
        System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
        System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);
         System.out.println("serviceprovider: " + serviceprovider);
        System.out.println("typeofcontract: " + typeofcontract);

    }



}

 class mymobile {
    public static void) {
        Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");
        Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.", "4","8", "GPS");
        Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
        Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
    }
}
```

any answers and replies would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `this.Mobile` doesn't make sense.

Comment: What line is the error reported for?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? `this."verizon"=service provider;`

Comment: It means the compiler found total nonsense.  (What do you expect this statement to do: `this.where 1024 = screen size;`?)

Comment: line 44 this.Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3 "GPS"); ,                I exepect it to create a new object for samsung mobile phone.

Comment: @Hot Licks i expect this statement to set the screen which i can use for the phone object, Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntax errors.

Comment: That statement's not even close to being legal in any programming language (though I suppose it vaguely resembles a SQL WHERE clause).

Comment: Understand that most sequential programming languages have the concept of "lval" and "rval".  An "rval" is an expression that can be evaluated to a single value (like 27).  An "lval" is something you can assign a value to.  The "lval" goes on the left side of the "=" (or whatever assignment operator the language uses) while the "rval" goes on the right.  This is one of the most basic, fundamental concepts of FORTRAN, C, BASIC, Java, et al.

Comment: (You really, really, really should not be writing phone apps.  Go back to writing simple little tutorial pieces until you've got at least the basic concepts down.)

Comment: this is the most horrible code I have ever seen. Don't even bother with writing tutorial pieces.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.2 = memory card capacity;
this.3=resolution;
```

Makes no sense at all.

You can't assign values to a literal (2, 3).

---

Edit: you would also need to fix this:

```
Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");
```

As stated by other members.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3 "GPS");
```

There's a comma missing after parameter value 3. I'd say that's your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Its a compilation error, it means The compiler was expecting a statement and you gave it something else please [refer](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html#NOTASTATEMENT)

Should be

```
Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mobile is a class,"this" stand for current object.So,You can't use "this" for Mobile.You should:

```
Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile("Samsung", 1, 2, "verizon", 3, "GPS");
    1024 = screen size;
    2 = memory card capacity;
    3=resolution;
    GPS = gps;
   "verizon"=service provider;
    typeofcontract = 12;
    checkcharge = checkcharge;
```

You need to replace the numbers in your `new Mobile` ctor call with reasonable values, as described by what must be comments/notes below, e.g., where you have a `1` put in the resolution (which makes no sense unless it's indexed or something), where you have a `2` put in the memory card capacity, where there's a `3` put in the resolution, etc.

Then either comment out the lines that are garbage, or, preferably, delete them.